# Dynamically accessing Resource metadata from inside a function in the Serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I just started using Serverless framework.

I was trying to deploy an endpoint that connects to RDS from a lambda, so I defined a handler, a route and a resource in the serverless.yaml file:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  environment:
    RDS_DB: mydb${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
    RDS_USER: foo
    RDS_PASSWORD: bar

functions:
  foo:
    handler: foo.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: api/v1/foos

resources:
  Resources:
    RdsCluster:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
      Properties:
        AllocatedStorage: 5
        DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
        Engine: MySQL
        MasterUsername: ${self:provider.environment.RDS_USER}
        MasterUserPassword: ${self:provider.environment.RDS_PASSWORD}
        DBName: ${self:provider.environment.RDS_DB}
```

Now I would like to write the code that connects to the database in the foo.handler and in order to do so I need to obtain the database host:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '<db_host>',
    user: process.env.RDS_USER,
    password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.RDS_DB
});
```

Is there any way to get this information dynamically from the serverless.yaml resource definition instead of hardcoding it in the handler itself?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this can be done using Fn::GetAtt to pass the value as environment variable:

```
custom:
  rdsHost:
    'Fn::GetAtt': [RdsCluster, Endpoint.Address]

functions:
  foo:
    handler: foo.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: api/v1/foos
    environment:
      RDS_HOST: '${self:custom.rdsHost}'
```